# can't change fontFamily when using themedata light/dark constructors

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i add fontfamily to the ThemeData.dark().copyWith()

```
ThemeData dark = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: ThemeColor.kdarkThemeBackGroundColor,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: ThemeColor.kdarkThemeBackGroundColor,
    backgroundColor: ThemeColor.kdarkThemeContainerColor,
    indicatorColor: ThemeColor.kdarkThemeShimmerDarkColor,
    splashColor:ThemeColor.kdarkThemeShimmerLightColor,
    // fontFamily : 'PatrickHand', // i want to add fontFamily to my themeData 
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
ThemeData dark = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  fontFamily : 'PatrickHand'
  primaryColor: ThemeColor.kdarkThemeBackGroundColor,
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: ThemeColor.kdarkThemeBackGroundColor,
  backgroundColor: ThemeColor.kdarkThemeContainerColor,
  indicatorColor: ThemeColor.kdarkThemeShimmerDarkColor,
  splashColor:ThemeColor.kdarkThemeShimmerLightColor,
);
```